# retrain model when I am only interested of a subcategory of the existing classes

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-serving, object-detection-api

I want to use a trained model form the tensorflow object detection API, specifically I want to use faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid_v4 trained on google open imaged. I am not interested in detecting all the 601 classes, but rather would like to detect 10 subclasses. Will I gain improvement in accuracy if I retain the last layer or is it  better to filter the layers I am not interested after the model is done with prediction. If I went with retaining, is it ok to retain the model with images form google open images again or it is better to use different data.

Answer (score 0):

[This official example](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining) seems to help you.